# Typescript Overwrite Constructor Arguments in Mixin

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, ecmascript-6

In my current typescript project I'm trying to create a mixin so that I can create multiple child classes that inherit from different base classes.

It all works well, but I can't seem to figure out how to tell typescript that the new derived class has different arguments than the base class. Here's an example that illustrates what I'm trying to do here

```js
interface ConstructorFoo {
  bar: string,
}

class Foo {
  public bar: string
  constructor({ bar }: ConstructorFoo) {
    this.bar = bar
  }
}

interface ConstructorBaz extends ConstructorFoo {
  qux: string
}

type FooType = new (...args: any[]) => Foo
const quxMixin = <T extends FooType>(base: T) => {
  return class Baz extends base {
    public qux: string
    constructor (...args: any[]) {
      super(...args)
      const { qux } = args[0] as ConstructorBaz
      this.qux = qux
    }
  }
}

const FooBaz = quxMixin(Foo)


const q = new FooBaz({
  bar: '1',
  qux: '2'  // Argument of type '{ bar: string; qux: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConstructorFoo'.
            // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'qux' does not exist in type 'ConstructorFoo'.
})
```

But I get the following error as I don't know how to specify `class Baz` has different argument types:

```
Argument of type '{ bar: string; qux: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConstructorFoo'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'qux' does not exist in type 'ConstructorFoo'.
```

Thanks for your help and here's [a playground link detailing exactly what I want to do](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsQGcxQK4JjpQBi66yA3gFDLIBGcUAXMjlKAOYA01AvtWoIANnCxZkZCjToAHPPWHAEDJq3ZdayBJnYEiUABSVVUZH1YZsufcSkBKKlrpgAFsCwA6RmYC8prQEBagB6EOQAFVcUTnQ4YWR0GGQARTwADwBZYHTQZA9kIm0oCDhIBnQ3ZDhJcjT07VFxaokAdwhhBLFq2vQAISYBgC9GsSxqUEhYRBQrPUJiAbMIdMgQABMJOZsF0nInOkYh9VwuXmCRMd6l5BW1zd6D5HlFZVVjtlOQTi0da3xdshDExOFhLLodgYlo4ZHQ2HhZNBgVBQfZnNoIVR3uZkP4QeM4YV3F4jrj3oF+IJJtB4Eg0BCAVC4CM7hANlsGbY9tItABHDInDjfSnUMAAT0RvQiEpQ-hAEFaQM8yvxrDgIDFAG0ALqOXwAPl6Qkx-KyOTy-gAPBFbqs2Q8pNLEfrDIwsBBWBE9YbYSUwHgoCBRs1hrb7hI3ShYXIFEoVKbBZpCX95gYlSqUWDqhqdTD0XQsAikcrPPi0YS6CmwFjTTi8ZnNQAGbUten-LnDfNEjyeWv+U3ogR0IKCKvXZlk03ZXIgQwOUcmsnyxVSYbGLQ+VgAcgAjFveHQE8gtwAmLd0MLIACCKLwAFs2dWkoUZceTJvPkLOABuZBHjTfL+fDngUICVC0WDAJwIBwIoKBFLITBwA+UyJMk4qSlu2yMnY5Bbp4XYVsgl4APL0AAVhAhDIEoUzxMgd5wGKiQgMIzFYIiCDADAzEANZga0QayFA6CIlAYDABAWDcNm6zHqa57rOgUnIGB1YrB41Z5BhKBYZyuxSPh-Bosa2DoMIECeMI6CcIYvImZeACS6ylJ0zHxFg6ChOEY6roME79hk06gHO5DQt5GLWMgMD0PQS4KuOUBru+ajHnA+7vNu6UyUeW7peYJlAA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```ts
/** A constructor that constructs a T using the arguments A */
type Constructor<T, A extends unknown[]> = new (...args: A) => T
/** Exclude the first element of an array */
type Tail<T extends readonly unknown[]> = T extends [unknown, ...infer U] ? U : never

interface Qux {
  qux: string
}

/** Add the Qux type to the first item in an array */
// If the T is empty, T[0] will be never and T[0] & Qux will also be never, so
// this needs to check if the array is empty
type AddQux<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [] ? [Qux] : [T[0] & Qux, ...Tail<T>]

// quxMixin accepts a constructor base and returns another constructor
const quxMixin = <C extends Constructor<any, any[]>>(base: C): Constructor<
  // that constructs the original class with the qux property
  InstanceType<C> & Qux,
  // using the same arguments as the original constructor except that the first
  // parameter includes the qux property
  AddQux<ConstructorParameters<C>>
> => {
  return class Baz extends base {
    public qux: string
    // args must be any[] due to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37142
    constructor (...args: any[]) {
      super(...args)
      const { qux } = args[0] as Qux
      this.qux = qux
    }
  }
}

const FooBaz = quxMixin(Foo)

const q = new FooBaz({ bar: '1', qux: '2' })
q.qux // string
```

This uses the utility types [`InstanceType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) and [`ConstructorParameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#constructorparameterstype):

```ts
/** Obtain the return type of a constructor function type */
type InstanceType<T extends new (...args: any) => any> = T extends new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any

/** Obtain the parameters of a constructor function type in a tuple */
type ConstructorParameters<T extends new (...args: any) => any> = T extends new (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Byi1wIopIguVMPcBovuAiZwSGQh2pqBTcMw2KxpbBUkXqKzCMiE+A5Gg4Ao0JbviTc6XHnRmr23KHXtoG5bkwQLIkgRBCLw-ClKINAHiaR4nggZ5tqueCGBmpCEDuFKoqgQHEnIIQQVwtzYggaQZFw8E8HeD5Plsr42nag5NvmaAAArEUItxIL+LiSG6bifN8FZVtUaSXuAABCRAAF79nM1CzsWHwbt8cgYByqTMDAvz-OAgLsOpm7EiEbDUAITCkPKk57CYGBZEiBAoCgcjhESJ6EFpATwAIwACLpj6yjkKDAN+CgAMowGgzC0sAVJII5SDAAAzAA7AAjAALAATCZqHNnggTBKEER2dEInfNVSXPiVATmUgkQmd8bYfPpbwglMjVMnsRaiq8LWcFSAR3p4CYmWC3xgmC1wiFs9yPOArF5uoABicBIlVs5oAC6BAoBs2theSDUBtW0bpp2m6YWu2GftxmtSuRV+O8t3gCCy57ux52VSZGpIAEO1TDtG4zVcbXnbJCnja8nasH4v0QyovxTN4vhQ-Jr23READkmW47oCZ47luMfc1PyjXCW5GWwQA)

Comment: Works great! A little question tho, what should i do if the base class is extended from another class and I want to add constraint and maybe type hint inside the new constructor

Comment: @Zaya if you wanted to ensure that `base` extends another class `T`, you could change `C extends Constructor<any, any[]>` to `C extends Constructor<T, any[]>`, but you would need to add a type assertion somewhere. Feel free to ask a new question if that doesn’t answer your question.

Note: I’ve updated my answer slightly to include less `any`s